# Require not vs. require do not

Tags: grammaticality

Which one is correct? I'm confused about whether I should say "require that someone does not do something" or "require that someone not do something"

> The Insurance Bureau requires that commissions and bonus do not exceed additional premium from policies sold.

vs.

> The insurance Bureau requires that commissions and bonus not exceed additional premium from policies sold

Comment: Both are grammatical and they both mean the same thing, though they have different derivations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first sentence, the nominal clause ("that commissions and bonus do not exceed . . .") is in what many call the indicative mood. This requires that the simple predicate ("do") be finite, and here it is conjugated for the third person plural in order to agree with its subject ("commissions and bonus"). (Note that an auxiliary verb, such as "do", is usually required in the indicative mood when "not" is included.)

In your second sentence, the nominal clause is in what many call the present subjunctive mood. This requires that the simple predicate ("exceed") be in the bare infinitive form. No auxiliary verb is needed.

As John Lawler indicated in a comment, both are grammatical and they both mean the same thing.